# How to set value for executionRoleArn in boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs

I am new to AWS and I cannot figure out how to successfully run a task in Fargate using an image from ECR using Python boto3. Here's what I do:

create the client

```
ecs_cli = boto3.client(
    'ecs',
    aws_access_key_id=access_key,
    aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,
    region_name=region
)
```

register a task definition

```
response = ecs_cli.register_task_definition(
    family='what_is_family_06_06', #i dont get what's a family
    networkMode='awsvpc',
    containerDefinitions=[
    {
        "name": "rand_name_06_06",
        "image": image_name,
    }
    ],
    cpu = "256",
    memory = "512",
    requiresCompatibilities=['FARGATE']

)
```

and run the task

```
response = ecs_cli.run_task(
cluster='default',
launchType='FARGATE',
networkConfiguration={
    'awsvpcConfiguration': {
        'subnets': [
            'subnet-03fc922da97e2d95e',
            'subnet-08a73abb757cf2fab'
        ],
        'securityGroups': [
            'sg-04a3379a63a69cb74',
        ],
    }
},
taskDefinition='arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:420295140958:task-definition/what_is_family_06_06:1',                  
)
```

I get this error:

```
"Fargate requires task definition to have execution role ARN to support ECR images."
```

That means I have to add `executionRoleArn='something'` to register_task_definition()

However in e.g., [this tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_AWSCLI_Fargate.html), there is no mention of executionRoleARN in Task Definition and in the boto3 [docs for creating a task definition](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecs.html#ECS.Client.register_task_definition) it doesn't say what specifically the value of  `executionRoleARN` should be.

I've looked at [Optional IAM Permissions for Fargate Tasks Pulling Amazon ECR Images](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_execution_IAM_role.html) but that did not help me.

I have created the IAM Admin User following [this tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/getting-started_create-admin-group.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that executionRoleArn is required, is because the image in the container definition(s) is from ECR which is a private repository.

ECS include the base execution task role policy [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_execution_IAM_role.html).

You can either modify this and create a new policy or attach the managed policy of `AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy` to your IAM role.

It is important when you create it, that it is created with a trust relationship for `ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com`.

Once you've created the role get its Arn, this is accessible from either the console or via the [list-roles](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/iam/list-roles.html) command on the CLI.

Take this arn and add to `register_task_definition` as shown below

```
response = ecs_cli.register_task_definition(
    family='what_is_family_06_06', #i dont get what's a family
    networkMode='awsvpc',
    containerDefinitions=[
    {
        "name": "rand_name_06_06",
        "image": image_name,
    }
    ],
    cpu = "256",
    memory = "512",
    requiresCompatibilities=['FARGATE'],
    executionRoleArn='ARN'
)
```

Comment: Thank you! I have followed the steps in the link you mentioned and added the following line to the register_task_definition:

         executionRoleArn='arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy'

           However, I get "An error occurred (ClientException) when calling the RegisterTaskDefinition operation: Role is not valid". Do you perhaps know what I am doing wrong? Thanks again!

Comment: Did you create it as an ecs role? If not edit trust relationships to add it. Use service name in answer

Comment: I've got it now!! This is what I needed to add for it to work: 'arn:aws:iam::420295140958:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole'. Thanks a lot I've been struggling with it for quite a while! :)